# Retrieve list of all repositories from a github user (public and private ones)

Tags: python, github, github-api

Hello everyone I'm trying to create a very simple python script that creates a list of tuples, repository name and clone url for each repository (public and private ones) of a github user owns. I have read a lot of threads about it but none solved my issue. There is no problem in getting the public ones. I have create a personal access token with full repo scope but I manage to retrieve only the public ones again.

I have tried making requests like this:
https://api.github.com/users/my_username/repos?access_token=my_personal_access_token

I have also read about pygithub3 library but I would prefer not to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`/user/repos` API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-repositories-for-the-authenticated-user).

`/users/<username>/repos` will only return the public repositories for obvious reasons, and it is also [documented](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-repositories-for-a-user) (emphasis is mine):

> Lists **public** repositories for the specified user.
>
> GET /users/:username/repos